# How to change axios content from "text/html" to application/json type in Nestjs

Tags: node.js, json, axios, nestjs, httpservice

I discovered that axios is returning a string instead of a valid json.

```
headers:Object {date: "Tue, 02 Jun 2020 08:44:06 GMT", server: "Apache", connection: "close", …}
connection:"close"
content-type:"text/html; charset=UTF-8"
date:"Tue, 02 Jun 2020 08:44:06 GMT"
server:"Apache"
transfer-encoding:"chunked"
```

how do I change the content-type to application/json in NestJs application?
I tried this but didnt not work

```
 const meterInfo = await this.httpService.get(url, { headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" } }).toPromise();
```

Here is the invalid json returned.

```
"{"status":"00","message":"OK","access_token":"2347682423567","customer":{"name":"John Doe","address":"Mr. John Doe 34 Tokai, leaflet. 7999.","util":"Demo Utility","minimumAmount":"13897"},"response_hash":"c43c9d74480f340f55156f6r5c56487v8w"}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending a `Content-Type` header, you should send an `Accept` header with the same MIME type. This tells the server what you are expecting to receive, and if Content Negotiation is set up properly, it will allow you to get a JSON back instead of that weird string.

```js
this.httpService.get(
  url,
  {
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
    },
  },
).toPromise();
```

If that doesn't work, you'll need to provide your own serializer to take the string from that wonky format to JSON, **or** get in touch with the server admins and see if they can provide you better documentation about how to consume their API.